# How can the inverse of the projection mapping in a product topology exist?

Tags: general-topology

I read that the projection mapping $\pi_x: X\times Y\to X$ is continuous. For this function to be continuous, the inverse $\pi^{-1}_x: X\to X\times Y$ has to exist.

Take any point $x\in X$. The inverse $\pi^{-1}_x(x)$ has multiple values- $(x,y_1),(x,y_2)$, etc. This is a one-many mapping. How come the inverse is defined then?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have a feeling the question really is about the expression $\pi_x^{-1}(U)$ where $U\subseteq X$ is open.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_image#Inverse_image

Comment: I just have one further question. Let $U\subseteq X$ be open. Then is $\pi^{-1}_x(U)=\bigcup_{i=1}^n (U\times V_i)$, where every $V_i\subseteq Y$ is open.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inverse, as a function from $X$ to $X\times Y$, is **not** defined (unless $Y$ is a one-point space). It **is** possible to define a **set-valued** inverse from $X$ to $\wp(X\times Y)$ that takes $x\in X$ to the set $\{x\}\times Y$, but it’s not possible to talk about continuity of this map unless one puts some topology on $\wp(X\times Y)$, the set of all subset of $X\times Y$.

Comment: Brian, like you said, I thought $\{x\}$ would be mapped to $\{x\}\times Y$. What does "put some topology" mean, and how woud one go about doing that here? Thanks

Comment: If you have a set $S$, you can talk about topologies on $S$: $\tau\subseteq\wp(S)$ is a topology on $S$ if it satisfies the usual conditions. This is true even if $S$ is a set of subsets of some topological space. It turns out that certain sets of subsets of topological spaces can be given useful topologies. The family of all non-empty closed subsets of a space, for instance, can be given the [Vietoris topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_space#Topological_constructions), and the family of finite subsets can be given the Pixley-Roy topology. I suspect that you don’t really ...

Comment: ... want to get involved with either of these just yet; you should probably be *really* comfortable with the more basic topological constructions first.